# How do I maintain user context in NodeJS project using Firebase SDK authentication?

Tags: firebase, api, firebase-authentication, backend

**How to identify the user?**

I have created 2 APIs for registration and login, but I am bit confused on how do I maintain the user context at back-end like, Do I have to generate the separate JWT token after getting successful auth response from Firebase on login and pass that to front-end or is there any method available in firebase SDK for validating/de-serializing the token received in login response.

**Following things I've tried so far.**

1. Gone through the firebase documentation and looked out for the availability of the feature to fulfill the requirement.
2. Asked ChatGPT about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- The Firebase back-end services pass the JWT back to the client.
- The client-side SDKs then stores it, and pass it with each call/connection to the server.
- The Firebase back-end services then [decode the JWT](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and verify it.